# Retornar dados da Data de acordo com o mês

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Desenvolvi a seguinte função:

```
public function get_agendas()
{
    $this->db->select("*, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data) as mes_referencia, count(id) as total_registros");
    $this->db->where("data >=", date("Y-m-d"));
    $this->db->group_by("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)");
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
    $consulta = $this->db->get('agenda')->result();

        foreach($consulta as $valor){
            $valor->lista_agenda = $this->db->get('agenda')->result();
        }

    return $consulta;
}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Na hora de listar todos os registros que pertencem a aquele mês, como eu faria o SQL?

Tenho 4 registros no banco de dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso exibir da seguinte forma:

Mes 04
      Registro 1
      Registro 2

Mes 05
      Registro 1

Mes 06
      Registro 1

A primeira parte, já sei que buscará quantos registros e consigo até exibir o mês corretamente, mas na segunda parte do codigo dentro do foreach(), não sei como fazer. Agradeço!

Comment: Você quer exibir a *quantidade* de registros por mês ou quer exibir os registros agrupados mês a mês?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta não está clara, então vou responder pelo que eu entedi.

Quando você quiser saber a quantidade de dados por um Mês especifico

```
select count(1) from horarioverificacao where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)=3
```

Abaixo se você quiser saber o total por meses

```
select  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data) ,count(1) from horarioverificacao 
group by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data)
```